# MInecart Roller Coasters in Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am currently attempting to build a roller coaster in Minecraft PE, and I know how to place the blocks. I wanted to make a straight drop down into the ground. Is that possible?

Comment: By "straight drop", do you mean a jump?

Comment: @TheFaster No, they mean like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Griffon_First_Drop.jpg

Answer (score 1):

No, minecraft rails can only be in a 45 degrees angle to the ground or completely flat. To make a straight drop, you need to literally make the minecart get off the tracks, and fall on another rail.

```
         <-
        _____
     |       \
 <-  V        \     <-
  _____/       \________
```

The arrows mark the direction of the minecart, the `/`, `\` and the `_` are the rails

The "landing" rail needs to be an angled one, or the minecart simply stops, when it lands on it.

Answer (score 0):

according to my experience, if you mean the rail goes downwards more than one block as the 'straight drop' than yes, but i recommend having the rails were the mine cart lands being angled down and in the direction you want the mine cart to go, in order to insure continuous motion

Comment: Can you improve your answer please? I didn't quite understand what you said.